# Is possible to use Express with Material Design for Web?

Tags: express, webpack, material-design

I have an *Express* app project and I want to use [Material Design for Web](https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started/) . Is there any way to do that because MDW needs Webpack witch run it's own server . Will not be there a conflict? .

Comment: Why would there be a conflict? If you are adding it to the HTML via a script tag it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: To start Webpack I need in package.json : "start": "webpack-dev-server", but to start Express I need : "start": "node ./bin/www" . I can run both?

Comment: I resolve the problem. Webpack is a file manager so it doesn't need to run a local server. The local server is to see the live changes of you sass file(s) and js (but there may be more). After the canges are good, `webpack` script will convert the sass and js files into css and js (the filename and location are specified in webpack.config.js), and the local server can run without webpack.